# Single or multiple word names of numbers

Tags: ortografía, números

Should numbers above 15 be spelled as a single word (*diecisiete*, *veintidos*, etc.) or multiple words (*diez y siete*, *veinte y dos*, etc). Does the Real Academia Española have a official opinion on the matter? What is the most common usage currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *just* read an article online that refers to this question. I am quoting it below for completeness. In summary, besides the traditional form, it is also valid to use forms such as `cuarentaicinco`, `setentaitres`, etc.

> La norma para escribir los números cardinales decía que a partir de treinta y uno iban separados, cuarenta y ocho, sesenta y nueve,
>   noventa y tres, excepto, claro está, los redondos, cuarenta, sesenta,
>   noventa.
>
> La Ortografía del 2010 admite ahora la escritura de esos números en
>   una sola palabra, cuarentaicuatro, cincuentainueve, sesentaisiete,
>   pero mantiene como válida la tradicional, cuarenta y cuatro, cincuenta
>   y nueve, sesenta y siete. Observe que en cualquier caso son
>   incorrectas las formas trentisiete, cuarenticuatro, cincuentinueve,
>   que tanto se oyen en la radio cuando dan la hora.

Source: http://www.eltiempo.com/vida-de-hoy/educacion/consejos-de-ortografia_10934724-4

Answer (score 5):

The Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas has [the official answer](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?clave=cardinales&origen=RAE) (unless the new Ortografía has changed it):

A **single word up to *veintinueve***, then multiple words:

- treinta y tres
- ciento cuarenta y cuatro
- quinientos dieciocho
- ciento tres mil cuarenta y tres
- ...

Comment: +1 for link to the official RAE guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

It's a single word up from *dieciseis* to *veintinueve*, then multiple words (*treinta y...*)

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. A Google search for "diez y seis" shows over a million results.

Comment: If you look at the search results for "diez y seis", they all refer to a particular event. Dieciseis is the accepted modern spelling.

Comment: @jrdioko jf you look here http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diecis%C3%A9is%2Cdiez+y+seis&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=10&smoothing=3 , "diez y seis" was widely used in the past.